# Why are foreign keys not saved on cascaded creation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    public void addGroup(final Group group) {
        groups.add(group);
    }

    ...
}
```

If I save each one individually, then everything is fine

```
Company company = companyRepository.save(new Company());

Group group = new Group();
group.setName("Managers");
group.setCompany(company);
groupRepository.save(group);
```

But if I try to shift the creation of groups on the shoulders of Hibernate

```
Group group = new Group();
group.setName("Managers");

Company company = new Company();
company.addGroup(group);
companyRepository.save(company);
```

then groups are created with an empty `company` field

```
db=> select * from groups;
 id |      name      | company_id
----+----------------+------------
  1 | Admins         |
  2 | Managers       |
  3 | Operators      |
```

I expected that Hibernate establishes relations itself. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are your database tables related by itself?

Comment: Do `group.setCompany(company);`, unless that `company.add` method is doing it, you only showed `company.addGroup`.

Comment: @Shadov it's just a typo.

Comment: @avix tables created by Hibernate.

Comment: Yep, then do it, I suggest adding `group.setCompany(this)` into `company.addGroup` method.

Comment: @Shadov It's so simple and so awesome at the same time! Thank you so much! Can you add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Maybe later I will write something longer than just `add this line` :)

Comment: You have a bi-directional relationship, you have to associated both the entities. Like Shadov said, associate group with company in the addGroup method.